# Run a SQL SELECT statement with values from different arrays - while the array is not empty

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2003, vba

I am trying to run a SQL statement from Excel using vba. All I need to do is run the select statement and use the values in my array Array1 and Array2. Array1 and Array2 store the WHERE condition for two columns.

e.g.

```
for i=0 to UBOUND(Array1) 'UBOUND for Array2 will always be equal to UBOUND for Array1

sql = "SELECT name, address, state, zip WHERE 
fname='" & Array1(i) & "' AND lname= '" & Array2(i) &"'" 
open rs.sql
sheets(1).range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

Next
```

Seems like it does not seem to work. I think I am not using the loop correctly. Could any one suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot for looking into it.

**Edit 1:**

Connection parameters:

Below is the code:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


'database credentials
 Dim uName As String, uPass As String

 Dim strConnect As String
 strConnect = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & "Server=[servername]" & "Database=[dbname] ;Uid=" & uname & ";Pwd=" & upass & ";trusted connection=yes"


 cn.ConnectionString = strConnect
 cn.Open

 for i=0 to UBOUND(Array1) 'UBOUND for Array2 will always be equal to UBOUND for Array1

 sql = "SELECT name, address, state, zip FROM XYZ WHERE 
 fname='" & Array1(i) & "' AND lname= '" & Array2(i) &"'" 

With rs
 .ActiveConnection = cn
 .Open sql
 ...[code to check for EOF/BOF, if not EOF or BOF then paste in pre defined cells]


 sheets(1).range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

Next


 end with
rs.close 
cn.close
```

Comment: You need to post your **actual** code. The code you have posted is invalid - it requires numerous quotation marks and there should be a dot before `CopyFromRecordset`. Even the UBOUND is incorrect without brackets.

Comment: Thanks, Andy for looking into it. I mentioned that it's a sample code. Howvere, I made the edits to reflect the code that is actually in the module.

Comment: So presumably you receive an error, perhaps at this line `open rs.sql`. What is the full error message?

Comment: What database are you using? If it is Access then Name is a reserved word and needs to be enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: I am querying SQL Server db. The error is a "Type Mismatch Error". Did enclose all the columns in square brackets but still getting the same error. I am assuming this not the correct way to run the sql. I have spent couple of days in looking for a solution but the research has given me nothing.

Comment: If this is meant to use ADO then you'll need a connection object - like this `rs.Open sql, cn`. Please show the code for how you are connecting to the database (but don't include any real username or password data)

Comment: Thanks, added the code for establishing connection. I can't open a  recordset without establishing connection with server. I know at least this much. :P  BTW, Using SQL Server Native client drivers, just in case there are any specific questions related to why I am not using the default sQL server drivers in Windows.

Comment: You have a `SELECT` and a `WHERE` but no `FROM`. You need to specify which table to select the data from

Comment: I have the table name specified in my query. The query shown above is just a demo query but lets say it's a table XYZ. I am focusing more on running the query in a loop and substituting the query with array values than anything else. Please pardon the typos.

Comment: Is this a very trivial question or none of the experts have ever encountered such a scenario?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: I am getting an error on sql="..."

Comment: if your getting the error on `sql=".."` then it would seem that that there is a problem with Array1 or Array2.  Verify that they have values   to build the SQL with.

Comment: @vbalite can you tell what the `array1(0)` and `array1(ubound(array1))` values are? are they words or numbers? what does your sql table look like? What are the columns data types?

Comment: Overall this approach will preform very slowly on non-trivial sized data sets. This is unrelated to your current problem. Which I think @mehow has the right question for.

Comment: The array has string values and will have no more than 10 items. When I hover the cursor on array (i) in SQL statement, it says "array(1)=<subscript out of range>". I changed the way array was referenced to array(i,1) in SQL where clause but still getting the subscript out of range. That makes me wonder how should the array elements be referred to in the SQL.

Comment: Exactly how are you populating `Array1` and `Array2`?

Comment: Please refer to Edit 2 or the answer in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167858/read-cell-content-in-excel-parse-based-on-delimiter-and-insert-into-array?noredirect=1#comment26616510_18167858

Answer (score 0):

Finally got my head around it. Couple of things - 1. Array 1 was empty due to a formula error. Once I fixed that, I was able to get the query running. Second, followed the construct in the loop:

```
cn.open
 for i=lbound(array1) to rbound(array2)
    sql="SELECT name, address, state, zip FROM XYZ WHERE fname='" & Array1(i) & "' AND lname= '" & Array2(i) &"'""
    rs.open sql, cn
    sheets(1).range("A2").copyfromrecordset rs
    rs.close
 next i
cn.close
```